# If $f$ is a twice differentiable function, then prove that $f'(1)>1$

Tags: calculus

> If $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a twice differentiable function such that $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and
>
> $f\left(0.5\right) = 0.5$ and $f(1) = 1$. Then prove that $f'(1)>1$

Attempt: we assume $\displaystyle f(x) = x+(x-1)(x-0.5)=x^2-0.5 x+0.5$

Then $f'(x) = 2x-0.5$

So we have $f'(1) = 2-0.5 = 1.5>1$

Is above mention method is right, if it is not right then help me to solve it, thanks

Comment: Hint: $f'$ is strictly increasing function.

Comment: You can't take a specific $f$ to prove a statement concerning general $f$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$f(0.5)=0.5$, $f(1)=1$, so by lagrange's mean value theorem there exists a $c\in (0.5,1)$ such that $f'(c)=(f(1)-f(0.5))/(1-0.5)=1$.

Now since $f''(x)>0$, $f'(x)$ is increasing and $f'(c)=1$ for some $c\in (0.5,1)$ so clearly $f'(1)>1$.

Also you can't take specific examples to prove a general statement, so your answer is not proper.

Comment: +1, but note that most people would call this "the mean value theorem" and not Lagrange's theorem.

Comment: yep, i changed it